# MDC context gets reset to null

Tags: mdc

I have my webservice running on dropwizard. I am using the slf4j MDC to set 
various attributes in my webservice. Currently I have 2 service endpoints service1 and service2. Each of them calls a function func() where the attributes are logged using MDC. But when I later retrieve the MDC to log these attributes in a buffer appender, only service1's attributes are available in the MDC, service2's MDC context returns null. I am not clearing the MDC anywhere in my code. What could be the reason.

```
service1()
{func()
}

service2()
{
func()
}

func() {
MDC.put(x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the issue was. Although the func() being called is the same. service2() invokes the function in a separate thread pool. (Therefore the MDC dies within that thread pool. Whereas service1 invokes func() in the same thread, therefore it lives on and the attributes set in the context are available.
MDC's scope is within the thread.